# How can I close UIAlertController without button

Tags: ios, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I use UIAlertController and UIActivityIndicatorView as my loading indicator, And it will close until my app gets the server response. But when something wrong with my server or network my app will never get response, I can't get back my control from the AlertView, I want to know is there some method can close this AlertView by touching the screen.
And my UIAlertView is without title and any buttons.
Any hints will be thankful.

It crashed when I touch the screen, Here is my code:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                        message:@"正在装载页面...\n\n"
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
spinner.center = CGPointMake(130.5, 65.6);
spinner.color = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
[spinner startAnimating];
[alert.view addSubview:spinner];
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:alert action:@selector(stopWaiting)];
[alert.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Comment: How do you do network operations? Post some code.

Comment: you can do like that
[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Save your alert controller to some property (for example, `alertController`) and close it with

```
[self.alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

To do it by touching the alert add a tap gesture recognizer to alertController's view:

```
- (void)showAlert {
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                                                             message:@"Some message"
                                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                           action:@selector(closeAlert)];
    [alertController.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    self.alertController = alertController;

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)closeAlert {
    [self.alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                             completion:nil];
}
```

[image]

Comment: It crashed when I touch the screen, in the console it says "unrecognized selector sent to instance", is there something wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is not advised. Most of the time, it is suggested that you have some kind of button, saying "OK" or "Cancel" or something.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated and useful.